# One Ajax Call Not Working out of two on same page

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to get data using ajax, below are my code for calling ajax:

**Not Working :**

```
 $.ajax({
     type: 'GET',
     url: 'http://localhost/admin/Advertisers/records',
     data: {},
     success: function(msg){
        alert(1);

     }
 });
```

**Working:**

```
$.ajax({
     type: 'GET',
     url: 'http://localhost/admin/Categories/records',
     data: {},
     success: function(msg){
         alert(1);
     }
});
```

both call are on same page but one is work and another is not working, want to know what is the issue.?

Comment: How are you triggering these AJAX calls? Also, what do you see in the developer console?

Comment: in developer console i am getting this "Object { readyState=0, status=0, statusText="[Exception... "<no mess...d :: line 6" data: no]", more...}" while calling "url: 'http://localhost/sooha/admin/Advertisers/records'"

Comment: `sooha`? That's not in the example, you sure that belongs there?

Comment: check your server side code

Comment: if there is a problem with server side code than both should not work,in my case one is working and another is not working.

Comment: It is a problem with the server JUST for this resource `http://localhost/admin/Categories/records`. If the second one works doesn't mean 100% the first one should work too.

Comment: than what should i have to do in this case ?

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible that one ajax is working and another not, on  same page.

Only one possible reason here is **"add blocker"** as you are trying to get data from

```
http://***/admin/Advertisers/records
```

so please check that have you installed **add blocker** in browser?

Answer (score 0):

From your comment

> Object { readyState=0, status=0, statusText="[Exception... "no
>   mess...d :: line 6" data: no]", more...}

, you are getting an error from the server when you make that request, so the `success` callback is not getting called, but the `error` callback should get.

From your comment you have some problem at `line 6` in your code.

Try this and you should see an `alert` telling you that `you have errors` :

```
$.ajax({
     type: 'GET',
     url: 'http://localhost/admin/Advertisers/records',
     data: {},
     success: function(msg){
        alert(1);

     },
     error: function(xhr, status, error){
        console.log(xhr);
        alert(status);
        alert(error);
     }
 });
```

Comment: its give alert messag but how can i know that which type of error is coming ?

Comment: @s4suryapal you should use the Network tab (In chrome, or equivallent) Ctrl + Shift + J and see what the server responded

Comment: I updated the answer to add code that should alert the error the server is sending

Comment: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
 

var error = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

Comment: Updated the answer, apparently your error is malformed. Still, the problem is from the server, you should debug your code there.

Comment: First Alert "[object Object]", Second Alert "error", Third Alert "[Exception... "<no message>"  nsresult: "0x805e0006 (<unknown>)"  location: "JS frame :: http://localhost/admin/assets/js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js :: .send :: line 6"  data: no]"

Comment: thanks for reply, but if there is a issue with my code than both should not work, in my case one is working and another is not working.

Comment: No, that is not true. if one is working it is not necessary for others to work. And also what your alerts are showing you tells that: "No error message was set by you", "you have to look at line 6". Are you using *Django* ?

Comment: sorry, but i don't know what is "Django" ?

Comment: "Django" is a type of server written in Python language. It doesn't matter. Still, your problem is clearly on the server. Run a debugging tool. The answer I gave you is as much as we can do for you and is answering your question too...the first ajax **IS WORKING** but returns error.